# Custom CSS in Vimeo OTT

Tags: css, vimeo, typekit

I'm trying to edit my vimeo ott site with custom adobe fonts.

I've added the following:

```
  @font-face {
 font-family: din-condensed, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;;
  src: url(https://use.typekit.net/him0mtg.css);
}

.gigantic {
    font-family: din-condensed, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

but it is not showing up. I've tried adding the stylesheet `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/him0mtg.css">` to the top of the custom css box but it keeps auto deleting.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the TypeKit url is a CSS file, and not a font, you would need to use [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) and import it into the top of your existing CSS like this:

```css
@import url('https://use.typekit.net/him0mtg.css');

.gigantic {
    font-family: din-condensed, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```